# Unable to get THREE.Raycaster to intersect THREE.PointCloud

Tags: javascript, graph, 3d, three.js

[image: graphosaurus demo]

I'm attempting to get click events working on my WebGL based 3D graph library called [Graphosaurus](https://github.com/frewsxcv/graphosaurus). You can see my attempt [here](https://github.com/frewsxcv/graphosaurus/commit/0430980569c2e50838f6af1e06b4debdbe444ce8). I'm using [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_raycasting_pointcloud) as a template. Is it not working because I'm using [TrackballControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js)?

Comment: I can confirm the raytracer coordinates/direction are working correctly (as far as I know) https://i.imgur.com/QR1Kfzc.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to increase the [Threshold param](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1769fbfc6c994b51a54c15a5c096855fd3cb8a1a/src/objects/PointCloud.js#L27)